# Calling webservice using Stub

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Can you please help me out to findout the correct method to call webservice,Below is wsdl file

Eclipse Generated below Classes:

```
EmpLookup 
EmpLookupLocator
EmpLookupPort 
EmpLookupPortProxy
EmpLookupPortStub
EmpLookupRequest
EmpLookupResponse
```

wsdl:

```xml
<xsd:complexType     name="List">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element       maxOccurs="unbounded"
       nillable="true"
       name="anyType"
       type="xsd:anyType"
       minOccurs="0">
     </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  <xsd:schema    xmlns:stns="java:com.test.ws.emp"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="java:com.test.ws.emp"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:complexType     name="EMPLookupRequest">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element       maxOccurs="1"
       nillable="true"
       name="empName"
       type="xsd:string"
       minOccurs="1">
     </xsd:element>
     </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  <xsd:schema    xmlns:stns="https://test/empLookup"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    targetNamespace="https://test/empLookup"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:import     namespace="java:language_builtins.util">
   </xsd:import>
   <xsd:import     namespace="java:com.test.ws.emp">
   </xsd:import>
   <xsd:element     name="lookupEmp">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element        xmlns:tp="java:com.test.ws.emp"
        name="empLookupRequest"
        type="tp:EMPLookupRequest">
      </xsd:element>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
   <xsd:element     name="lookupEmpResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element        xmlns:tp="java:language_builtins.util"
        name="result"
        type="tp:List">
      </xsd:element>
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
 </types>
 <message   name="lookupEmp">
  <part    xmlns:partns="https://test/empLookup"
    element="partns:lookupEmp"
    name="parameters">
  </part>
 </message>
 <message   name="lookupEmpResponse">
  <part    xmlns:partns="https://test/empLookup"
    element="partns:lookupEmpResponse"
    name="parameters">
  </part>
 </message>
 <portType   name="empLookupPort">
  <operation    name="lookupEmp">
   <input     message="tns:lookupEmp">
   </input>
   <output     message="tns:lookupEmpResponse">
   </output>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding   name="empLookupPort"
   type="tns:empLookupPort">
   <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <operation    name="lookupEmp">
    <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="" />
   <input>
     <soap:body use="literal" />
   </input>
   <output>
     <soap:body use="literal" />
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service   name="empLookup">
  <port    name="empLookupPort"
    binding="tns:empLookupPort">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/empLookup/empLookup" />
  </port>
 </service>
```

How can I write samll class to make a call and get response? No idea at all on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to phpeveryday
It may have a solution to your problem
http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Web-Services-WSDL-Creating-SOAP-Server-P484.html